# Merging Chef attribute arrays

Tags: chef, chef-solo

Let's say I have two cookbooks, Foo and Bar. In cookbook Foo, attributes/default.rb contains the following:

`default[:test] = [{:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}]`

In cookbook B, I'd like to expand that array with another object (i.e. merge the two arrays): `{:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}`, ideally from within a recipe.

I tried to put the following Bar's recipe, or the attributes file:

`default[:test] = [{:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}]`

Expecting the two to get merged and result in:

`node[:test] == [{:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}, {:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}]`

But that is not what happens. Instead, only one of the two objects is contained in the array during a Chef-Solo run. I also tried with `default.override` and `default.set` with the same results. How can I merge the two arrays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add individual hash elements to an array you can do it using the insertion operator << instead of the assignment operator =

**In cookbook A**

```
# Create the default attribute as an array
default[:test]=[{:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}]
```

**In cookbook B**

```
# Using array insertion on an existing array
default[:test] << {:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}
```

If the runlist order is not guaranteed to be A,B then you need to guard against trying to insert into an array which doesn't yet exist.

**In cookbook A**

```
default[:test] ||= []
default[:test] << {:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}
```

**In cookbook B**

```
default[:test] ||= []
default[:test] << {:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}
```

If you want to merge 2 arrays just use +=

```
# In cookbook A
default[:test]=[{:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}]

# In cookbook B
default[:test] += [ {:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}, {:baz => 'E', :qux => 'F'} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Chef's DeepMerge method from inside the second recipe like:

```
a = Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.merge(node[:test], [ (new array here) ])
```

a will contain the deep-merged hashes!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work when I want to set node[:test] to the deeply merged array. Here's the exact code I'm running:

Cookbook1/attributes/default.rb:
`default[:test] = [{:baz => 'A', :qux => 'B'}]`

Cookbook2/recipes/default.rb:
`a = Chef::Mixin::DeepMerge.merge(node[:test], [{:baz => 'C', :qux => 'D'}])` followed by `node.override[:test] = a` This however results in node[:test] being empty.

Comment: I proposed an edit to change from `merge` to `deep_merge`. If there are conflicts the value in the first "source" hash will win.